# ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

Хочу переписать серверный код в es6, для этого в package.json указал "type": "module".

Webpack5 сразу же начал ругаться что require не поддерживается и я заменил на import, но теперь Webpack  не находит __dirname выводит ошибку:

`[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined [0]     at file:///Users/vyacheslav/programming/course/webpack.config.js:10:24`

Помогите понять как определить __dirname чтобы  Webpack его понял?

```
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import {CleanWebpackPlugin} from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

const outputDirectory = 'dist';


export default {
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
...
```

Comment: в es6 нет __dirname, __filename https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/chto-takoe-__dirname-v-javascript

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname

Comment: @nörbörnën спасибо! помогло

Comment: @Alexey Ten  спасибо, так как раз про это!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

добавил в webpack.config.js вот этот код

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```